# Run a php function when click on a button

Tags: php

I have a php script page with a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="clientmanager.php">
<input type="text" name="code_client" id="code_client" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

In my file "clientmanager.php", I have a function for example "addClient()".
I want to click the button and only call the function "addClient()" in the file "clientmanager.php" instead of call the whole file "clientmanager.php", So how could I do??
Thx!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call PHP Function from Action Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689164/call-php-function-from-action-form)

Comment: If that function represents its own HTTP resource call then you'll want to refactor it out of that file and into its own resource so that you can call it directly.  You can, alternatively, pass some flag along with the POST data and conditionally check for that flag in `clientmanager.php`, but that's bad design.  It sounds like `clientmanager.php` has more than it needs, and should be broken up into discrete units.

Comment: I suggest doing some research on PHP MVC frameworks such as CodeIgniter, CakePHP, and others. They use routing techniques to achieve that (mapping an URL to a specific class method/function).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of the file:

```
if (isset ($_POST ['code_client'])) addClient();
```

However, you should consider using a different setup - processing forms like this is considered **bad practice**.
Maybe create a separate file, use OOP, MVC, a framework, anything other than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that over jquery (ajax).

1. Call jquery library in head
2. Call clientmanager.php over this code:

**my_form.php**

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
...

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="code_client" id="code_client" />
<input id="my_button" type="button" value="Save" />
</form>


<div id="response_div"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#my_button").click(function(){


                $.post("clientmanager.php", {code_client: $('#code_client').val()}, function(data){

                    if(data.length >0) {

                        $('#response_div').html(data);

                    }//end if
                });


        });

    });

</script>
```

**clientmanager.php**

```
<?php

echo $_POST['code_client'];

?>
```